# Black screen while trying to set UITableView background to a UIView from xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, xib

I am trying to set a UIView (loaded from a xib file) as the background of a tableview. But when running the app on a device it is just showing a black screen and there are no errors. This is how i do it,

```
zoneListEmptyView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewEmptyState" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

zoneListEmptyView.bounds = self.view.bounds;
```

And in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` i check if data to be displayed is empty and if yes, i do,

```
 [self.tableView setBackgroundView:zoneListEmptyView];
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

I checked other similar questions in stack overflow and tried to recreate the xib and class files, but no help. I am displaying tableview empty states in another application using the same approach and it works fine,but not here. Please help

Comment: Hey I created and tried to replicate your code, i found it working, I guess you are doing something wrong. Let me tell you the procedure I Followed

I created a .xib file (by going to newFile -> user interface -> view)
Then took a global variable and assign the designed view on xib to it.
The use the condition if array count == 0, set the back empty ground view, the same code you mentioned here. Please post some more code if you still could not figure it out

Comment: @Janmenjaya thanks for your help. I am also doing it the same way. In fact i have the exact same code which works fine in another app, but not in this.

Comment: Try setting background color to view . I think you are setting black color somewhere for that view

Comment: @Vinodh thanks. But the view already has a background color. Also if i create a UILabel and try to set it as background view it works